# How to Create Co-Dependent Objects in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns

What are the options/patterns that I should be thinking about when I am creating co-dependent objects?  (I'm using PHP).  For example:

- I have an Organisation object that has a required Email property
- Oganisation is also a required property of Email

I am creating all objects in factories, so I have a fair degree of flexibility.  To date I have been relaxing the constraint on one of the objects, and giving it a setter that works once only.  For example:

- On the Email object I would make Organisation an optional property
- I would then add an `email->setOrganisation($org)` method, which would check that the value of Email::Organisation was null before going ahead and setting it.

But is there a better way?  One option I have thought about is creating a prototype object (in this case Email), and allowing prototypes only to be replaced.

Comment: A better way is to reconsider why you need a separate object for Email which also has the required property of 'Organization'. If these things are so tightly coupled, why are they separate classes?

Comment: Thanks pvg, I also need email as a property of User, for example.

Comment: Well, same thing applies. If two things you model are so tightly coupled, chances are one is a property of the other, rather than them being mutually properties of each other. An organization or a user might have a 'has a' relationship with an email, an email probably doesn't have such a relationship with a user or organization.

Comment: You are right, a User (or Organisation) definitely "has a" Email, and not vice-versa.  But I do need to navigate from an Email to its owner (since users sign in with their email address), and it would be a mistake to allow an Email to instantiate without its owner.

Comment: Can't you create email object inside Organisation?

$this->email = new Email($this);

Comment: First, you might want to think about whether you _really_ need Email to be an object, but lets assume that you do, for the sake of argument. Users don't sign in with Email objects, they sign in with strings. There's no reason for you to be instantiating an Email object before creating a user so your call could look something like `UserFactory.findUser($emailString)` which instantiates User and sets it up with your Email object, if you insist on having it.

Comment: I'll add a final more general comment - when designing your model, start with something simple and extend it as you figure out your requirements rather than modeling every 'concept' or 'entity' in the domain you can think of, whether it's useful for your application or not. Similarly, while the enforcement of constraints is a useful property of a model, not all constraints are useful. What terrible thing will happen in your application if a un-owned email object is instantiated? Probably nothing.

Comment: Thanks pvg, I think your last sentence says it all.